# File Upload Limit Exception from Tomcat Azure

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot, tomcat8

I tried uploading files to the server deployed in azure web app service.
In local it's working fine and when it comes to azure it throwing some exception. FileSizeLimitExceededException.

This upload service is developed in JAVA Spring boot version 1.5.8

> Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1048576 bytes

```
spring:
  http:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10MB
      max-request-size: 100MB
      enabled: true
```

Also tried some `@Bean` entity configuration also. It doesn't help me out.

Tried `web.config` with custom `server.xml` file specifying maxPostSize.

I need to set the maximum upload limit to 10MB.

Comment: Is there the [`SnakeYAML`](http://www.snakeyaml.org/) library on your classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you were using `application.yml` instead of `application.properties` as the configuration file for your spring-boot app. However, I'm worried about there is not a `application.properties` file in your project. And as the section `[24.6 Using YAML instead of Properties`][1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.8.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-yaml) of the Spring offical document for version `1.5.8` said,

> YAML is a superset of JSON, and as such is a very convenient format for specifying hierarchical configuration data. ***The SpringApplication class will automatically support YAML as an alternative to properties whenever you have the [SnakeYAML](http://www.snakeyaml.org/) library on your classpath.***
>
> [Note]
>   If you use ‘Starters’ SnakeYAML will be automatically provided via spring-boot-starter.

Therefore, there must be a `SnakeYAML` library in your project, whatever directly add a jar file or configure the maven `pom.xml` file, if without `application.properties`.

Comment: My problem has been sorted out by configuring the property file. Thanks for the help.